# Is android's lifecycle callback's considered a "coroutine"?

Tags: android, coroutine

Would it be proper way to describe Android's many lifecycle based callbacks in java, such as `onsaveinstancestate` a coroutine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  They're just normal functions, called on the main UI thread message queue at the appropriate times.  They don't have any special yield functionality.

Comment: Can coroutines be basically thought of as "manual" threads? (e.g. you have to manually make sure they yield to one and another and play nice) as opposed to actual threads where this is taken care of at the CPU scheduling level?

Comment: Sort of.  Closer to non pre-emptive multitasking, like Windows 3.1 or Mac OS until OSX.

Comment: Could you please talk to me as if I were a golden retriever? I assure you my proficiency at programming is not that great.

Comment: Most OSes today are preemptive multitasking.  It means the OS can tell stop the app that's currently running and start another app at any time.  Non-preemptive multitasking only allows application switches when the program yields the processor-  when it calls one of a set of functions to the OS which say "OK, you can run something else now".  For example disk IO or sleep().

Comment: Coroutines are kind of the same idea, but within an application instead of between applications.  Nonpreemptive OSes are dead for general purpose use, although some real time OSes may still use it.  It has major drawbacks for PCs, for example if a npe OS has an app enter an infinite loop, the entire machine is locked up.